# GuiceConfig and JSP_TEMPLATES_BASE_PATH

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey, jetty, guice

I have a GuiceConfig:

```
public class GuiceConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener
```

... with a configureServlets() method that does the following:

```
params.put(ServletContainer.FEATURE_FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, "true");
params.put(ServletContainer.JSP_TEMPLATES_BASE_PATH, "/WEB-INF/jsp");

serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, params);
```

This class feeds requests into a Resource using @Path("/admin/index"), which simply returns a Viewable JSP resource:

```
return new Viewable( "/admin/index" ) ;
```

When I run this source and access my local URL, localhost:8046/admin/index, I successfully retrieve the desired JSP resource.

However, I don't want to serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class).  Doing so will interfere with other modules that are running on my server.  I would like to only process requests pre-pending with /rest.  If I modify the above source to the following:

```
params.put(ServletContainer.FEATURE_FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, "true");
params.put(ServletContainer.JSP_TEMPLATES_BASE_PATH, "/WEB-INF/jsp");

serve("/rest/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, params);
```

I can now successfully access the local URL, localhost:8046/rest/admin/index.  However, though this page successfully returns, the JSP does not display correctly.  The console log indicates that the JSP resource, new Viewable("/admin/index"), resolved correctly... but the output from the page reads as follows:

```
Error 404 /WEB-INF/jsp/admin/index.jsp
```

I have been digging but have been unable to find an answer explaining this issue.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Per the servlet spec, the entire `/WEB-INF/` tree is inaccessible from normal requests.

However, it can be referenced internally, via various dispatch techniques.

The `Error 404 /WEB-INF/jsp/admin/index.jsp` seems to indicate that something attempted to directly reference that path.

If you hit your `http://localhost/admin/index` or `http://localhost/admin/index.jsp` what happens?